# Setting Auto Increment Start Value as a Variable in Access

Tags: variables, ms-access, vba, auto-increment

I've looked around online but can't find any clear answers for this. Is it possible to set the starting value of an Auto Increment field to a variable (example to follow) in MS Access VBA?

```
Private Sub Command10_Click()
Dim dbs As Database
Set dbs = CurrentDb
Dim tblTempMinID As String

tblTempMinID = "DMax(EntryID, tblCalendar) + 1"
dbs.Execute "ALTER TABLE tblTemp ALTER COLUMN EntryID AUTOINCREMENT(tblTempMinID)"

End Sub
```

I'm currently getting an error in field definition with the above code. Still doing research, but I figured it wouldn't hurt to put this out here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to increment by 1:

```vb
dbs.Execute "ALTER TABLE tblTemp ALTER COLUMN EntryID AUTOINCREMENT(" & tblTempMinID & ",1)"
```

Comment: Slubee, I'm still getting the same error even with updating to your suggestion. I was very hopeful that the solution was as simple as that though...

Comment: tblTempMinID = DMax("EntryID", "tblCalendar") + 1. why do you have dmax in quotes?

Comment: Thanks! That (mostly) took care of the issue. The reason I had dmax in quotes is that I'm still learning the proper way to write the code. I'm still relatively new at it. 

In order for me to get your corrections to work, I had make sure that there was already an entry in tblCalendar -- otherwise I was getting error 94 Invalid Use of Null. I removed the quotes from dmax as you suggested and put them around the table name and field name and didn't have any issues otherwise.

Comment: You could use `Nz()` to avoid *"invalid use of Null"* when *tblCalendar* is empty: `tblTempMinID = Nz(DMax("EntryID", "tblCalendar"), 0) + 1`  Also consider `Dim tblTempMinID As Long` (instead of String)